# BDD - Dynamically change a Ninject binding in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, bdd

I'm new to Ninject and I've set it up using my own NinjectDependencyResolver class as per:
http://www.shahnawazk.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html

I'm trying to setup BDD cross-process mocking ala Steve Sanderson's post here:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/09/deleporter-cross-process-code-injection-for-aspnet/

Steve suggests something like:

```
Deleporter.Run(() => {
    var mockDateProvider = new Mock<IDateProvider>();
    mockDateProvider.Setup(x => x.CurrentDate).Returns(dateToSimulate);
    NinjectControllerFactoryUtils.TemporarilyReplaceBinding(mockDateProvider.Object);
})
```

How would I implement TemporarilyReplaceBinding so that I can dynamically change the binding in my MVC3 project from my Spec project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason why you cannot use Steve's implementation of the [NinjectControllerFactoryUtils](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/Deleporter/blob/master/Samples/WhatTimeIsIt/WhatTimeIsIt.IntegrationTest/Infrastructure/NinjectControllerFactoryUtils.cs) class (and the [TidyupUtils](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/Deleporter/blob/master/Samples/WhatTimeIsIt/WhatTimeIsIt.IntegrationTest/Infrastructure/TidyupUtils.cs) class) in the WhatTimeIsIt project on GitHub?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see Steve's samples on github